# Link style matter : the link is getting a select box on opening the popup

Tags: html, css, joomla

I am faceing a strange matter, I am using toolbox pop up in a Joomla theme. if you click  for Example in the link here: http://kfzgutachter-vaatz.de   and then select for example "Verkehrsunfall – Was nun?"
when the popup appears there are 2 links, the first link is being marked with abox like it is selected, how can I remove this one or where it is coming from?

Comment: Please read: [Something on my website doesn't work, can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it) and create a snippet with a [mcve] in the question

Comment: Please try->  a:focus{outline: none;}

And let me know any changed or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because your link has focus when you open the modal. In fact if you click somewhere inside the modal, the link is no more underlined because it loses focus.
You can add a javascript code to set the focus on the modal once you have opened it using [.blur()](http://api.jquery.com/blur/).

Answer (score 0):

The "box" you are seeing around the link is a focus event. If you would like to disable just this inside of the popup.

Use the below code:

```
.uk-modal-dialog a.popup-link:focus {
    outline: none;
}
```